# Making texture mirror on back of plane

Tags: texture-mapping, 3dsmax, uvw

I have recently started up using 3DS Max after an period of 6 years break. I am trying to create an game tile / brick for a board game with a number on each sides. I have made the tile from a box with chamfered sides for it to look a little smooth on the sides. I have created an material with texture, a square image with a number in the middle. I have attached this to the box and added UVW map and chosen plane in the UVW map and it works fine besides the number on the back is mirrored. How do I solve this?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "brick" is a "dice" ?

Since your just getting back to 3ds max,
you should follow some up to date tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qxT0J-lrYM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMWgbznoEC0

Your problem is that you most likely made a tiny mistake, in your development

What version of 3ds max are you using ?

Good luck